# Unable to intercept traffic for Flutter iOS app performance testing

Tags: flutter, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

We are trying to conduct a performance test on iOS app built on Flutter. However, when we try capturing the requests through blazemeter/jmeter, we are unable to intercept the proxy. On further investigation, we found that mobile applications developed using Flutter do not follow the proxy settings defined on the mobile device, and make use of its own certificate store.
Is there any other way to intercept the traffic for Flutter app for iOS? or is there any other way to conduct performance test on Flutter iOS app?

Tried capturing the traffic by following steps given in following site - https://medium.com/@viniciuscorrei/using-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios-directly-from-mobile-applications-b5dc5bc48ef6, however, all requests were not being captured.

Answer (score 1):

In order to record iOS application you need to:

1. Install JMeter's certificate into your operating system, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102390) for the certificate
3. Configure Wi-Fi connection to use the machine running JMeter as the proxy
4. Disable cellular data completely

Be informed that you can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) traffic, if your Flutter app (whatever it is) uses other network protocols - you won't be able to record.

More information: [Configure Apple Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690550545-Configure-Apple-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)